# Problem while implementing EditText field dynamically

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am entering floating numbers into my EditText fields and want to calculate the result based on some logic as below and display the result in a TextView.I wanted to know what is the problem with this method since I am getting error with this particular method.I know its a simple thing but then I am an Android beginner.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.bmi);
            bmi1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            bmi2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
          bmi3=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.bmiText);


    bmi2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable ab) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
            calRes();
        }
    });




    ImageButton ImBtn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    ImBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent newIntent=new Intent(Activity1.this,DragNDropListActivity.class);
            startActivity(newIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });

}

    public void calRes() {
        String a; 
         String b;  
        float c;
         a =  bmi1.getEditableText().toString();   //gets you the contents of edit text
         b =  bmi2.getEditableText().toString(); 
         c=  Float.parseFloat(a)/(Float.parseFloat(b)*Float.parseFloat(b));    
         bmi3.setText(String.valueOf(c));
    }

}
```

### Error:

```
     08-29 12:05:03.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     08-29 12:05:03.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299): java.lang.NumberFormatException:         lengte in metre
     08-29 12:05:03.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.initialParse(FloatingPointParser.java:130)
     08-29 12:05:03.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseFloat(FloatingPointParser.java:319)
     08-29 12:05:03.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:291)
     08-29 12:05:03.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at  com.android.mds.health.nursing.formula.Activity1.calRes(Activity1.java:87)
     08-29 12:05:03.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at com.android.mds.health.nursing.formula.Activity1$1.onTextChanged(Activity1.java:45)
     08-29 12:05:03.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
     08-29 12:05:03.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:6172)
     08-29 12:05:03.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:6316)
     08-29 12:05:03.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:889)
     08-29 12:05:03.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:400)
     08-29 12:05:03.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:269)
     08-29 12:05:03.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:432)
     08-29 12:05:03.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:218)
     08-29 12:05:03.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:28)
     08-29 12:05:03.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspace(BaseKeyListener.java:60)
     08-29 12:05:03.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.onKeyDown(BaseKeyListener.java:123)
     08-29 12:05:03.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.text.method.QwertyKeyListener.onKeyDown(QwertyKeyListener.java:327)
     08-29 12:05:03.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(299):     at android.text.method.TextKeyListener.onKeyDown(TextKeyListener.java:132)
```

Comment: can you give error log trace ?

Comment: @user370305:I have added the error log.

Comment: @Chirag Raval::I have added the error log

Comment: Call `calRes` on onclick. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

```
bmi3.setText(String.valueOf(c));
```

do this

```
bmi3.setText(""+c);
```

**EDIT:**
Use `valueOf` instead of `parseFloat`

```
  c=  Float.valueOf(a)/(Float.valueOf(b)*Float.valueOf(b));
```

**Edit 2 :**
Calculate the BMI when all values are entered into the `edittexts`. Have a button and call `calRes` in `onClick` of the button. You are getting the exception because calRes gets called when you are still entering the first field and rest fields are empty. Empty fields are causing the crash coz there is no value in them to be converted.

Comment: user7777777777:Even then I am seeing no changes.

Comment: @user7777777777   Float.parseFloat() its also worked fine. I think Problem in string values.

Comment: I am entering 100 in one EditText field and whenever I want to enter the value to the other EditText field it gives me error.

Comment: You are calculating the value at the wrong place. Call calRes after the edittext has lost focus.

Comment: Caluculate the BMI when all values are entered into the edittexts

Comment: k, try put a button in layout and on button click make this calculation.

Comment: I am not getting any changes.Anyhow thanks a lot for your help.+1 each:-)

Comment: I got the answer now according to @user7777777777.Thanks a lot  user7777777777 and user370305  for your help:-)

Answer (score 1):

ok, after watching your code its seem to, you have a problem in parsing string to float,

If you have a not problem of values of string a and b, then it should work fine.

look, I have a tried this its work perfect,

```
       String a,b;
       Float c;
      tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_test);
        a =  "100";   //gets you the contents of EditText
        b =  "10"; 
        c=  Float.parseFloat(a)/(Float.parseFloat(b)*Float.parseFloat(b));    
      tv.setText(String.valueOf(c));


Edit: Also take care of your editText input its have only numeric values in string
format, not any characters or special symbols.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of this,

```
    a =  bmi1.getText().toString();   //gets you the contents of EditText
    b =  bmi2.getText().toString();
```

you should try this,

```
    a =  bmi1.getEditableText().toString();   //gets you the contents of EditText
    b =  bmi2.getEditableText().toString();
```

Comment: :I am seeing no changes even after making it as EditableText().

Comment: I have edited my code to the entire class.Please take a look.

Comment: Try like this,  bmi3.setText(Float.toString(c));

Answer (score 0):

If any alphabet or special characters in your `EditText` (bmi1 & bmi2 , a ,b) then this error must be coming so please check your value of EditText using `System.out.println`..becuase float Variablt must be numeric and dot (.)

Answer (score 0):

from looking at your initial error it seems as though you are trying to parse a float from the string 'lengte in metre'. Is this the text of a label in your layout? It sure is not a parseable number:)
Maybe if you are still having problems you can post the xml layout file.

Anthony

Comment: I got the solution for that.Anyways thanks:) I have a small doubt.How to set the decimal upto two values(i.e. #.##) in my EditText field dynamically?

Comment: Add a textChangedListener to your EditText and check in there how many places of decimal have been added. If they have 2 alread, don't accept any more input. I am not aware of a straightforward mask method that you can use.